# Create Users as followers with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I wonder how to create a follower table with Users generate with Devise.

Further more I created a Users Controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

I think I have to create a table like this

```
Follows
----------
   id
----------
user_id

=> rails generate model Follow user:references
```

But I think in the `Follower Model` I have to use `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

Please could you guide me please. Thank for your help.

I read some tutorials but I didn't understand where we create `following_id` and `follower_id`

Comment: What you are looking for is a self-referential association. See if this helps: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: @omarvelous I want to have `users`can follow and be followed by others users. Only that. Do I create an other table?

Comment: Did you check the link? It is exactly what you are looking for... You would just replace "friendship" with "follow" in your case.

Comment: @omarvelous yes but something went wrong when I try to do this what means `nifty` in `nifty_scaffold`?

Comment: nifty is some custom scaffolding gem, ignore that. You can replace `nifty_scaffold` with `scaffold`.

Comment: @omarvelous Thank you it works.